# train test split is not splitting correctly

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am still a beginner in AI and deep learning but I wanted to test whether a neural network will be able to calculate the sum of two numbers so I generated a dataset of 5000 numbers and made test size = 0.3 so the training dataset will be equal to 3500 but what was weird that I found the model is training only on 110 input instead of 3500.

The code used:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from random import random


def generate_dataset(num_samples, test_size=0.33):
    """Generates train/test data for sum operation
    :param num_samples (int): Num of total samples in dataset
    :param test_size (int): Ratio of num_samples used as test set
    :return x_train (ndarray): 2d array with input data for training
    :return x_test (ndarray): 2d array with input data for testing
    :return y_train (ndarray): 2d array with target data for training
    :return y_test (ndarray): 2d array with target data for testing
    """

    # build inputs/targets for sum operation: y[0][0] = x[0][0] + x[0][1]
    x = np.array([[random()/2 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(num_samples)])
    y = np.array([[i[0] + i[1]] for i in x])

    # split dataset into test and training sets
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=test_size)
    return x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # create a dataset with 2000 samples
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = generate_dataset(5000, 0.3)

    # build model with 3 layers: 2 -> 5 -> 1
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, input_dim=2, activation="sigmoid"),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
    ])

    # choose optimiser
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)

    # compile model
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')

    # train model
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100)

    # evaluate model on test set
    print("\nEvaluation on the test set:")
    model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)

    # get predictions
    data = np.array([[0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.2]])
    predictions = model.predict(data)

    # print predictions
    print("\nPredictions:")
    for d, p in zip(data, predictions):
        print("{} + {} = {}".format(d[0], d[1], p[0]))
```

[image]

Comment: How do you see that it's training on 110?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 I edited the question to include a photo of the result you can see it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `110/110` you are seeing in your image is actually the batch count, not the sample count. So 110 batches * the default batch size of 32 gives you ~3500 training samples, which matches what you'd expect as 70% of 5000.

You can see by backing into it the other way that the last batch would be a partial batch, since it's not evenly divisible by 32:

```py
>>> (.7 * 5000) / 110
31.818181818181817
```

In neural networks, an epoch is a full pass over the data. It trains in small batches (also called steps), and this is the way Keras logs them.

Comment: I felt that there is something wrong when I watched this video https://youtu.be/JdXxaZcQer8?t=1020
it shows 3500

Comment: I think this due to different versions but I am not sure